# Casting Combobox.SelectedItem back to DateTime causes "Specified cast is not valid."

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, casting

I have the following code which appears correctly populates a combobox

```
    class Hour
    {
        public string shownHour {get;set;}
        public DateTime atime {get;set;}
    }

    (...)

    DateTime now = new DateTime();
    now = DateTime.Now;

    List<Hour> hours = new List<Hour>
        {
            new Hour{shownHour = "8:00 AM", atime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 8,0,0)},
            new Hour{shownHour = "8:30 AM", atime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 8,30,0)}
        };

    comboBox1.DataSource = hours;
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "atime";
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "shownHour";
```

I'm seeing the "8:00 AM" and "8:30 AM" correctly populate and selectable in the combobox. However, when I attempt to retrieve the ValueMember in the ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged event I'm getting a "Specified cast is not valid." error. I can't seem to retrieve it back with the following code.

```
DateTime StartTime = (DateTime) comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

In the debugger, I'm seeing the atime from the combobox.SelectedItem and it does appears to be formatted as a DateTime type but I can't seem to cast it back. Am I approaching this problem incorrectly?

**Solution**: as @Cj S pointed out below, Combobox.SelectedItem was returning the Hour type where I thought it would be returning data of Hour.atime of type DateTime. Using the solution given gave the correct information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cast a string to a DateTime.  Use DateTime.Parse instead.

Comment: @Cj S. Doesn't SelectedItem return the ValueMember which should return hours.atime of type DateTime? Why would it return a string?

Comment: Completely spaced thought I was looking at a ajaxcontroltookit problem :-)  Anyway, if you stop your debugger on the line that's throwing the cast exception, you'll see that the SelectedItem property is an instance of Hour (or null if the user enters their own value in the combobox).  So cast to an hour and then pick off the atime.  Like this ` DateTime StartTime = ((Hour)comboBox1.SelectedItem).atime;`

Comment: @Cj S. Yes! I was just trying that and found it was returning the Hour type but you got to the answer already! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your combo is DataBinded then you need to do the following.

```
int intId = ((Priority)comboPriority.SelectedValue).Id;
```

Where `Priority` is my Entity Class

Answer (score 0):

Oops...

I was completely wrong. You need to get the `SelectedValue` instead of the `SelectedItem` like this:

```
DateTime StartTime = (DateTime) comboBox1.SelectedValue;
```

<strike>I believe that your selected item is the of the type `Hour` and you are trying to cast it as a `DateTime` I believe your code should be somethign like</strike>

```
DateTime StartTime = (DateTime) comboBox1.SelectedItem.atime;
```

Comment: @LWK I tried to use combobox1.SelectedValue but it still gave me the same error of "Specified cast is not valid."